# How to pass multiple parameters to a function dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I have created a Util API's to create function object and to invoke its function API's

```
function FunctionUtils() {

}

FunctionUtils.createFunctionInstance = function(functionName) {
     var obj = FunctionUtils.createFunctionInstanceDescend(window, functionName);
     return new obj();
}

FunctionUtils.createFunctionInstanceDescend = function(obj, path) {
     var parts = path.split('.');

     for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
         obj = obj[parts[i]];
     }

     return obj;
}


FunctionUtils.invokeAndInflate = function(object, functionName, parameterValue) {
     object[functionName](parameterValue);
}
```

This Util API's work for below code:

```
function Student() {

     var firstName;

     var city, country;

     this.getFirstName = function() {
          return firstName;
     }

     this.setFirstName = function(val) {
          firstName = val;
     }

     this.getAddress() {
          return city + country;
     }

     this.setAddress(val1, val2) {
          city = val1;
          country = val2;
     }

}


var student = FunctionUtils.createFunctionInstance("Student");
FunctionUtils.invokeAndinflate(student, "setFirstName", "Pranav"); //Works

FunctionUtils.invokeAndInflate(student, "setAddress", "LA", "USA"); //Doesn't Work.
```

How to use FunctionUtils.invokeAndInflate API for more than one parameters ? ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite the `FunctionUtils.invokeAndInflate` function as below:

```
FunctionUtils.invokeAndInflate = function(object, functionName, parameterValue) {
    object[functionName].apply(object, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2));
}
```

Comment: You can drop the arguments from the function call, if you want, and get them all from `arguments`. The last one at least should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you reading about .call() and .apply(), here is an article about them.
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx